# WordPress MU Domain Mapping Customizer Error

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I am using WordPress MU Domain Mapping which works fine, but when I try to these any theme's customizer, I get this error when trying to save:

**Cheatin’ uh? Sorry, you are not allowed to customize this site.**

When I deactivate the plugin, the customizer works. I have 'Remote Login' and ' Redirect administration pages...' unchecked in the options as well.

Comment: have you tried making another superadmin and logging in as that user? clearing cookies, etc. Just a guess, but i'm wondering if the domain mapping isn't recognizing your permission from a session previous due to the mapping. sub.site.com is now subsite.com and when the function calling up customizer checks your cookie says sub.site.com so it throws an error. I'd make a new user and log in from a different browser to eliminate that as a possibility at least.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but yes, I tried another super user account and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, I found the cause to be a conflict with the WP Super Cache plugin, I had to disable the following from my wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping without a plugin then. Since WP 4.5 this is possible. Just point the domain to the server with A record and change the site URL by editing the site.
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping

Or contact the plugin developer here and report the issue: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to map it directly but I did try to contact the developer directly but haven't heard back yet

Comment: Mapping them directly still displays the error when saving in the customizer. I made sure to delete the sunrise.php file as well.